# Oracle SQL update

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried searching for this particular topic here, but haven't found the answer... Anyway, my aim is to update table (let's call it t_item), specifically column owner_id with values depending on another table (t_item_geo which is in turn linked to t_geo).

I'm not entirely sure whether the syntax below is actually valid for update statements.

```
UPDATE t_item SET owner_id= 6993 WHERE t_item.owner_id in
(SELECT t_item.owner_id FROM
t_item,
t_item_geo,
t_geo
WHERE
t_item.id = t_item_geo.item_id and
t_item_geo.geo_id = t_geo.id and
t_item.owner_id in (SELECT id FROM t_user WHERE network_id='fffffff') and
t_geo.id in (SELECT id FROM t_geo WHERE full_name = 'yyyyyyy')
);
```

Anyway, my problem with this query is that it updates far more rows than it should - if I separate just the select statement Oracle returns ~750 rows but the udpate itself updates more than 4000 rows. It's almost as if the condition was completely ignored - which would point me to perhaps incorrect syntax.

I need to update specific value in the table based on the select from few other 'joined' tables. Hope it makes sense.

Thanks for any contribution!

UPDATE: sorry - maybe it wasn't clear from the question itself, but the correct number of edited items should be ~750 and not ~4000. Thanks!

Comment: this should work - even i fthe subselect has 750 rows, there could be 4000 in the t_item table that match those ids

Comment: I agree with Randy, if owner_id is not the PK (or a unique column) on this table, there could be lots of rows that match those 750 identifiers

Comment: Well, you can use a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and find out if it's valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but unfortunately they don't really help - I need to update the t_item table based on the result of the sub-select. It works the other way around - I'm able to select the records I need to modify but I'm having trouble transforming it into an update statement (hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
MERGE INTO t_item
USING 
(
    SELECT t_item.owner_id FROM
    t_item,
    t_item_geo,
    t_geo,
    t_item.rowid rowid_sub 
    WHERE
    t_item.id = t_item_geo.item_id and
    t_item_geo.geo_id = t_geo.id and
    t_item.owner_id in (SELECT id FROM t_user WHERE network_id='fffffff') and
    t_geo.id in (SELECT id FROM t_geo WHERE full_name = 'yyyyyyy')
) on (rowid = rowid_sub)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET owner_id= 6993;
```